# Room Owners can star(real star, not pin) their own messages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

If we **pin a message two times**, it'll become a star instead of pin. For example:

1. I posted a message:
   [image: my own message]
2. I'm about to pin it:
   [image: about to pin]
3. It has been pinned now:
   [image: pinned]
4. But if I click *pin this message* again:
   [image: about to pin it again]
5. The pin will be removed, but there's a star on it:
   [image: starred]

---

As @Thaillie said in the comments, when I click *unstar as interesting*, it shows *You can't star your own message*. And the star is still there:

[image: unstar my message]
[image: can't do it]

Comment: Can reproduce http://i.stack.imgur.com/RRtvW.png

Comment: Can reproduce http://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Yl6.png. Also, clicking the "unstar as interesting" results in the "You can't star your own message" popup and does not affect the star.

Comment: Might be related to the fact that `\star` is a kind of toggle and `\unstar` is an RO only option but that is only exposed on the starboard I think. Here is some background: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262239/158100

Comment: @rene: Hmm...understand. When I click the *unstar as interesting* actually it sent a star post (the url is `http://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/27471078/star`). So if I do `$.post('http://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/27471078/unstar', {fkey: 'xxxxxx'})` manually it be unstarred  successfully.

Comment: @rene: Oh, when I pin a message, it sent a post to `http://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/123456/owner-star`, first time it pins a message, second it become a star, then become a pin again, and become a star again, etc, etc. And `\unstar` can remove them, but `\star` will raise an error.

Comment: It's a known "secret" feature, although I don't have the link explaining it.  With great power comes great responsibility. ;-)

Comment: If you want to get rid of the star, you can go to the starboard and click "cancel status" in the menu for that message.

Comment: Cross Site Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157871/chatroom-owners-can-star-their-own-messages

Comment: @davidism: Ah, still think if it's a feature, it should be little clear. However this confused me :P. And I agree with the last part ;)

Comment: @KevinGuan it's a "secret feature" or "easter egg" like the "`[tag:status-...]`" on meta.SE chat.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Ah, that's fine. :P

Comment: @TinyGiant: Now you've got me curious. What exactly do the status-* tags do in chat there?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: [Typing \[status-*\] in chat shows red moderator tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57129/typing-status-in-chat-shows-red-moderator-tag)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>Now let me *end* this question.</sub>

So as Nathan said in comments, this should be a Cross Site Dupe: [Chatroom owners can star their own messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157871/chatroom-owners-can-star-their-own-messages)

> As such, this is currently [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) – although at the time balpha seemed willing to entertain reasons why the behaviour should be changed, if you have a compelling reason.

(Also Shog9 edited the tags and added [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign))

---

<sub>Funny part</sub>

However, as davidism and Tiny said, **this is a easter egg**. But **no**, I don't like this because it confused me...but doesn't matter, because ***I found some more*** : [What Easter Eggs do the chat sites have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75861/what-easter-eggs-do-the-chat-sites-have)

[image: Ỹ̢̢̨͖̝̑̐́͌ͅǫ̖̞̩̼̎̒̔̃͡͡ų̴͖̯̜͖̗̄̂̌̇͌͛͊̌͢ c̲̪̱̠͍̩̏̋͌̎̔̒͘͘͘͡ͅa̛͕̟̹̘͖̓̍̄̉̑n̸̡̞͇̪̠̳̩̉͌͐̋̄͂̾̅̕͡'̵̮͉͉̥̥̒̈́̈̓̒͂͌̒͡t̡̧͕̦̼̀̂̀̍̽͆́ p̧̛͉͕̠̗͓̭͗̽͂̃a̺̜͈͔̰͇̅́̎͆̍͋̆̚͟r̡̡͓͙̺͔͈̲̻͌̊̽̽̔͜͞͞s̶̘͚̗̞̥͉̻̗̀͊͑͌́͐̕͡e̮̤̦̦͉͈̗̗̰̝̓̌́̿͗͐̇̽̕͞ [̢̬̼͖̲̜̫̽̓̆̋̏͂͗̚ͅX͔̠͓͍̮͖͌̿̂̒̾́̾͟]̧̩̰̫̳̟̟̲͛́̐͑̌́H̛̹̹̣̞̟̥͎͒̃̊͟͢͝T̢̛̰͚̻͕̼̩́͗̌́͑̃M̢̧̠̟̻̦̤̓͌̂͊͒͒̿̌̎̆͟L̨̟͖̝̻̻͓͍͓̽̀̔̾̈͌̾ w͇̱̰̥̼̠̳̠̲̄̒̈̿͒ͅį̣̺̽̈́͌̔͒͜͜t̪͎̭̞̱̙͔̅̋̀̀͒͞ḧ̴̼͓̣̤́̾̉͐̓̌́̄̽͢ͅ r̭͎̦͎̞̝̻̊̃́̀̄ͅe̱͙̰̭͉̽͂͆͌̊͢g̷̢̣̮̲̮̜̥̳͇̀́̈́̈́̕ẻ̵̢̝̣̮̃͑̾̄̎̍ͅx̮̖̙͙̺̬̱̣̆͑̀̿̈.̵̤̗͕̖̥̔̉̽͐͋͐̄́͠]

Comment: BTW, don't try to edit my answer, you'll be crazy  ;)